Implementing search-triggered display in Laravel Filament 3 table
I am working with a table in my application and I want it to display no data until a search has been performed initially. I initially want the table to be blank and only display data when a Company_Name is searched. How can I achieve this? Here is the code for my table:
public static function table(Table $table): Table 
{
    return $table->columns([
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Rep_No')->searchable(),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Our_Ref')->searchable(),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Company_Name')->searchable(),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Feature_Name'),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Issue'),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Advert_Code')->searchable(),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('CopyType')->searchable(),
        Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('Date_Confirmed'),
    ]);
}

